# Timeout or try-catch for connecting to a server? (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient

Which code is preferable to handling failed connections to a server?

[Something like this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795574/c-how-do-i-stop-a-tcpclient-connect-process-when-im-ready-for-the-program-to/1853133#1853133)

Or this kind of code at the beginning of the async callback for `TcpClient.BeginConnect`:

```
try
{
    tcpClient.EndConnect(async);
}
catch
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("uh oh");

    return;
}
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your context is handling connection timeouts, I assume that you mean you have not yet received a response from a request made, within a certain period of time.

Wrapping your `EndConnect` in a try block and catching any exceptions thrown does not necessarily constitute a timeout occurance. There is currently no in-built support for handling timeouts with `TcpClient`. 
Your first link is a good example of how to detect and work with connection timeouts.

This article may be of some help to you also: [Using an asynchronous client socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Does it really matter if it is a timeout or not though? Basically if anything goes wrong wouldn't I want to cancel the entire operation? Wouldn't the first example fail for other types of errors?

Comment: By no means am I saying your catch block (for error handling) is a bad idea, simply that I don't believe it is a graceful or elegant way of handling connection timeouts (which if you think about it, may not be considered as an **exceptional** case).