# How to set the the timeout for an asychronous Connection with a TcpClient?

Tags: c#, timeout, tcpclient

I've been looking at numerous examples such as [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2281199d-cd28-4b5c-95dc-5a888a6da30d/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795574/c-how-do-i-stop-a-tcpclient-connect-process-when-im-ready-for-the-program-to/1853133#1853133), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795574/c-how-do-i-stop-a-tcpclient-connect-process-when-im-ready-for-the-program-to/3769871#3769871) but none of them seem to work. I'm not sure what's wrong but for each example I've tried the wait is just ignored and I just get the standard unhandled socket exception in approximately 1 second, regardless of the specified wait time. `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Here's an excerpt to help understanding:

```
public void Connect(string host, int port)
{
    tcpClient.BeginConnect(host, port, OnConnect, null);
}

private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult async)
{
    tcpClient.EndConnect(async);
}
```

Been trying a bunch of different examples but for all of them my client application either just failsfast after a second or throws a socket exception. Would a try-catch be a better solution here and just avoid using WaitHandles?

Comment: All of those examples should work. Use the first one end step through your code. It's impossible to get a socket error before `EndConnect` is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.

usually means that there is nothing running on that port on the remote machine, or there is a firewall somewhere blocking the request.

there is a

`tcpClient.SendTimeout`

and `tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` to answer your specific question, but it probably isn't your issue here.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to handle connections failing when the server is not listening. Do I just have to use a try-catch to handle that because SendTimeout and ReceiveTimeout do not solve this problem either.